# How to convert List of objects with JSON string to Excel

Tags: c#, json, excel

There is a Job history management class structured like follows:

```
public class JobHistory
{
    public int SubJobID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Data is a JSON string. I can control the logic to have the same schema of this JSON in a set of List.

Now I wish to convert List to an excel file that extract the JSON to excel columns with the same level of Code and Message. How can I design this part?

JSON string only has one layer data.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be excel file format then i would suggest using a library like [Npoi](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) to create the file, can serialize from an object and produce excel files.

Other wise as suggested use a csv.

Comment: I've done basic HTML tables into Excel using Npoi and it is a great library to work with.

Answer (score 0):

it have to be excel? cant it be a CSV as excel opens CSV files and its much less work to generate.

Comment: csv is okay for generation.